# How to center a navigation bar properly?

Tags: html, css, centering

I understand, lots of people have asked this question on how to center a navigation bar but when I apply this CSS, it centers it but it aligns the nav bar a bit to the right:

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Could this be due to some list items having different lengths or do you think this is a different problem?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thank you so XUFOX it helped i've had this question for a long time but hadn't asked it. thank you very much.

Comment: @Paulie_D While it’s true that, in general, such questions should contain more code to add more context, in this case it was luckily a common enough problem to answer it without any HTML by just knowing the CSS applied by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<ul>` most likely has a `padding-left`, as this is the default. Just check for it in the developer tools.

```css
nav {
  background: #999;
  text-align: center;
}
nav li {
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[image: 40px of padding on the left is the default.]

Just apply `padding-left:0;` on the appropriate `<ul>` to fix this.