# White bar under my menu and my ul can't stay center inside my menu

Tags: html, css

So i have this weird weird white bar right under my menu. Ive been deleting some stuff and adding margin: 0 0; to some stuff, i can't find where it come from! Also why is my ul all over the place, it won't stay center.

Html:

```
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="spa.css">
       <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
       <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Year%20of%20Dog-32.png" />
        <title>Acceuil</title>
    </head>


    <body>

    <div class="nav">
      <div class="container">
                        <div class="right">
                         <a href="https://www.facebook.com/SPA-Thetford-Mines-54177071330/" target="_blank"><img src="1445918850_Like.png" height="30" width="30"></a>


                <p>Heure d'ouverture</p>
        </div>

      <div class="logo">
       <img src="1445919066_cat_sleep.png" height="45" width="45">
       <h1>SPATM</h1> 


        </div>


        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar">

                        <ul>
                <li><a href="spa.html">
                <img src="kennel1.png" height="42" width="42">Acceuil</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html"><img src="running37.png" height="42" width="42">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="adoption.html"><img src="dog56.png" height="42" width="42">Adoptions</a></li>
                <li><a href="don.html"><img src="donation3.png" height="40" width="42">Faire un don</a></li>
                <li><a href="perdu.html"><img src="pet55.png" height="42" width="42">Perdu et Trouvés</a></li>
                <li><a href="contac.html"><img src="woman93%20(1).png" height="42" width="42">Contactez-nous</a></li>              
            </ul>
 </div>


       <div class="main">
       <div class="info">
        <h2>Bienvenue sur le site de la SPATM <br>
        (Société protectrice des animaux de Thetford Mines).</h2>

           <h3>Notre mission</h3>
           <p>La SPATM est un organisme à but non-lucratif qui a pour mandat de protéger les animaux, mais aussi d’informer et d’éduquer la population sur les différents besoins des animaux domestiques et des animaux sauvages. Nos efforts sont concentrés surtout sur la prévention et le contrôle de la population animale. Nous conseillons les propriétaires d’animaux en espérant améliorer ou bien démarrer leur relation avec leurs petits compagnons de vie.</p>

        <h3>Notre établissement</h3>

        <img class="imgmain" src="spabuilding.jpg" width="400" height="280">

<p>La SPATM a ouvert ses portes le 11 juin 2007. Notre établissement est composé de locaux pour l’adoption (chats et chiens), de locaux pour la quarantaine (chats et chiens) et d’un local d’isolation. Les locaux de la quarantaine servent a accueillir tous nos nouveaux pensionnaires afin de donner la chance aux animaux errants de se faire réclamer et de pouvoir évaluer la santé et le comportement de chacun d’eux avant de les transférer à l’adoption si tel est le cas. Le local d’isolation nous permet d’accueillir des animaux pouvant être contagieux sans risquer de contaminer les autres. De plus, nous avons une salle de lavage pour effectuer la désinfection de notre matériel de nettoyage et du matériel utilisé pour nos animaux (bols, laisses, colliers, plaques d’identification, cages de transport, ect.) et celle-ci contient un bain pour laver nos animaux. Une salle d’examen est aussi mise à notre disposition pour faire les examens physiques et pour procurer des soins comme la coupe de griffes, le rasage et autres soins à nos animaux.</p>

      <h3>Notre équipe</h3>

       <p>Notre équipe est composée de deux techniciennes en santé animale diplômées, d’un patrouilleur animalier, d’une animalière et d’un conseil d’administration. Nous sommes tous qualifiés pour répondre adéquatement aux clients et nous possédons plusieurs années d’expérience dans le domaine animalier.</p>

       <h3>Vous êtes les bienvenus!</h3>

       <p>La SPATM est ouverte au public, les animaux mis à l’adoption peuvent être visités sur nos heures d’ouverture. Les bénévoles pour distraire nos pensionnaires sont toujours les bienvenus et bien appréciés. Nous avons souvent la présence de chiens de grandes races qui demandent beaucoup d’exercices.</p>

        <p>Tous nos pensionnaires sont bien entretenus et toilettés au besoin. Tous les chiens sont sortis trois fois par jour afin qu’ils puissent faire leurs besoins à l’extérieur, sans compter les promenades de nos visiteurs. Les chats peuvent quotidieement se dégourdir les pattes pendant que nous nettoyons leurs cages.</p>

        <div class="footer">              
  <p>  © 2015 Société protectrice des animaux de Thetford Mines
</p>

    </div> 
      </div>




    </div>

    </body>   
</html>

css:
```

```css
   body {
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 1.625;
        margin:0 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }


html{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size:100%;
    margin:0 0;
    padding:0px;
}

.nav {
    font-family:'Merriweather', serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding:0;
    line-height: 18px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    text-align:center;
}

.nav h1 {
    color:#4A96AD;
    float:left;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.nav p {
    display: inline-block;
    color:#4A96AD;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 14px;
    float:right;
}


.right img {
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    clear:right;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left: 17px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    padding:2px
}

.right{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.logo{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.logo img{
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.info {
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom:0;
}

.info h2, h3 {
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top:30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.imgmain {
    float:right;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 1px;  
}

.info p {
  margin-bottom:50px;
}

.navbar a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #F5F3EE;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size: 20px

}

.navbar li {
    margin: auto;
    display:inline;
    margin-left: 15px;

}
.navbar ul {
    margin-top:0px;
    text-align:center;
}

.navbar img {
    position: relative;
    top: 13px;
    width: 4%;
    margin: auto;
    height:100%;
    margin-right: 3px;
    background-position: center; 
}

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: rgb(58, 145, 232);
    border-radius: 35px;
}
.main {
    background-color:rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.42);
}

a:hover {
    color: rgb(255, 180, 35);
}

.footer {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top:0;
    border-top: 2px solid;
    text-align:center; 
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.footer p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top:20px;
}

.container {
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.imgdisplay {
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-image:url(rsz_3d0bcd96798d63581f56fa86e77dd8b0.jpg);
    height: 500px;
    width: 1024px;
    background-position: center; 
    margin: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uc53L1u5/

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/uc53L1u5/1/) how do you want it? Sincerely, I didn't understand your question. A simple draw will help a lot to help you.

Comment: To center the `<ul>` set `padding: 0;` to it. This part of your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/31564871/4642212.

Comment: And the white bar comes from the `margin-top` of the first `<h2>` in `<div class="info">` in `<div class="main">`. A little inspecting and debugging helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

@Lucio http://imgur.com/vwwf6kk

Comment: Great, got the idea. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/uc53L1u5/2/) is like you want to. Remove the styles for `.navbar li` and apply [this](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12986242/) to `.navbar ul`

Comment: Thank you so much, you're awesome !!